# ssms hide (1 row(s) affected)

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2012

When running code, SSMS 2012 is writing `(1 row(s) affected)` into the messages window for every line in mydataset. This isn't unexpected (see details below) but is there any way to suppress these messages, while still getting important error messages?

I am executing code that uses a cursor to WHILE loop through a table and do some rather complex comparisons to prior records and manipulations, then collect the results in a @Temp table before writing it out to the database:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--do stuff here, then collect the results

INSERT @Temptable(value)
SELECT @value;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @value
END
```

SSMS 2012 writes `(1 row(s) affected)` into the messages window for every `INSERT`, which makes sense, but is annoying in this case, and since I'm on a lousy VPN where bandwidth is precious, the chattering back and forth has some impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your script, or wherever you want to begin suppressing the "x rows affected" messages.   To resume seeing them later in the script (if desired), put in `SET NOCOUNT OFF;`

Comment: My Google-Fu was not strong enough for this. Thank you.